# IIS windows integrated Auth

Tags: windows, asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have a one way trust with a foreign domain, they access my web application hosted in IIS using windows integrated auth.. problem i am seeing for every new request iis does the auth agains the DC using netlogon logs.. is there a way to cache the windows auth in IIS for the either browser session?

Comment: I imagine there's a good reason for that to be the default way of handling authentication attempts. If you disable a user, a cached credential may be your undoing. Have you considered using Active Directory Federation Services? This achieves what you're after but at the cost of implementing a couple of new servers. It removes the need for the trust since it's all done through ADFS but it will scale nicely if you choose to start providing your application to other businesses. If you're interested in ADFS, check out: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2(WS.10).aspx